# How to implement swift subscript setter for enum associated value

Tags: swift, enums, subscript-operator

Trying to get the following to work:

```
enum Foobar {
    case values([Int])
    case singleThing(Double)

    subscript(index:Int) -> Int? {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .values (let numbers):
                return numbers[index]
            default:
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            switch self {
            case .values (let numbers):
                numbers[index] = newValue!
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code won't compile. It complains about the fact that I'm updating `numbers` when I assigned it with a `let`. So I tried replacing that `let` with `var`. Which compiles. But does nothing, because the it updates a value copy of the associate array, rather than the original array itself. At least that's what I think happens.

Is there an approach that will allow me to have associated values that are subscriptable and implement the `set` property when appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
case .values (let numbers):
    numbers[index] = newValue!
```

`numbers` is a *local variable* which is bound to the current associated
value. Even with `var numbers`, you modify only this variable, not
the instance of the enumeration.

```
case .values (var numbers):
    numbers[index] = newValue!
    self = .values(numbers)
```

should do what you expect. (Note however that calling the subscript
setter with `nil` will crash your program.)

Comment: @TravisGriggs: That is totally up to you, nobody can help you with that :)

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a couple problems.

- It isn't possible to change the associate values of an enum
- In your case statement

  - you're defining `number` to be a constant which is not mutable
  - `number` is a copy of the associated value because arrays are structs which are passed by copying

It's better if you treat enums as value types that are not mutable, it makes everything easier. You could use a struct or a class instead if you need a mutable type.

If you really need it to function this way, you can get it to work by changing the case to look like this.

```
case .values (var numbers):
    numbers[index] = newValue!
    self = .values(numbers)
```

Comment: Did one help more than the other? We have the same code but technically I was a 2nd answer.